# $G$ is finite abelian group, do we have $\{ng : g\in G \} = G$ for $(n, |G|) = 1 $ (coprime)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

$G$ is finite abelian group, do we have $\{ng : g\in G \} = G$ for $(n, |G|) = 1 $ (coprime)?

I think it is true, we know $G$ is the direct sum of finitely many cyclic groups $$\mathbb Z/p_1\mathbb Z\oplus \cdots \oplus\mathbb Z/p_m\mathbb Z.$$ 
We will have $m$ generators in the from $(1,0,\cdots,0), (0,1,\cdots,0),$ ... And $(n,0,\cdots,0), (0,n,\cdots,0)...$ will still be the generators since $n$ and each $p_i$ are coprime.

Is this correct? And is there a more direct argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map $x \mapsto nx$ is a homomorphism, because $G$ is abelian.

The map is injective because its kernel is trivial since $\gcd(n,|G|)=1$. (*)

Therefore the map is surjective, because $G$ is finite.

(*) Indeed, let $m=|G|$ and take $u,v \in \mathbb Z$ such that $un+vm=1$.
If $x$ is in the kernel, then $x=1x=(un+vm)x=0$.

Answer (score 7):

You proof is correct and looks like the easiest one. Here's one without using the fundamental theorem of fg abelian groups, but on the same spirit: By Bézout's theorem, take $k,l\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $kn+l|G|=1$. Then for every $g\in G$, $g=(kn+l|G|)g=n(kg)$.